# display multiple pin balloons simultaneously (pins share common title text)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any method that will allow multiple Google Map location pins to display their attribute balloons simultaneously, when all the pins share the same text string in their pin title?
eg I have plotted the addresses of 3 branch offices of a business on a My Places map. Each branch office has the same 'business name' as their main pin title. When I click on any one of these 3 pins, I want all three of them to **simultaneously** display their info text balloons.

Comment: Show us what code you've got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method in the API to do that but you can easily setup your own. This involves to create multiple infowindow objects.

Create an array to hold your markers. Create each marker and the corresponding infowindow. Push each marker to the array, along with the infowindow object.

```
markers.push([marker, infowindow]);
```

On marker click, loop through the markers array and check each title. If it corresponds to the clicked marker title, open the corresponding infowindow.

```
function markerClick(marker) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        if (markers[i][0]['title'] === marker['title']) {

            markers[i][1].open(map, markers[i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/XcyKq/

Comment: well played sir! Many thanks for that code & jsfiddle demo - it's great.

Comment: *** Just out of interest, is it then possible to force all open info balloons to close, by clicking on a different (unopened) marker pin?

Comment: The same idea applies here. You can add your own properties to the infowindow. Here I created a `groupTitle` property. Then you can loop through the markers array and call the `close()` method of the infowindows. http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/XcyKq/5/

Comment: You mentioned to force *all* infowindows to close. I thought you meant to close them by group. In this case, no need for the `groupTitle`. Simply loop through the array and call the close method on each of them. You get the idea.